# ruby space after the function(method) in ruby language

Tags: methods, expression, space, between

Why puts ("hello world").nil? in ruby language is not the same puts("hello world").nil?

difference in the sentence above is in space.
puts ("hello world").nil? and puts("hello world").nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `puts("hello world").nil?`, `ruby` will think the paranthese as function call:

```
$ ruby -rripper -rpp -e 'pp Ripper.sexp("puts(hello world).nil?")'
[:program,
 [[:call,
   [:method_add_arg,
    [:fcall, [:@ident, "puts", [1, 0]]],
    [:arg_paren,
     [[:command,
       [:@ident, "hello", [1, 5]],
       [:args_add_block, [[:vcall, [:@ident, "world", [1, 11]]]], false]]]]],
   :".",
   [:@ident, "nil?", [1, 18]]]]]
```

In this case, parenthese is **arg_paren**.

If you use `puts ("hello world").nil?`, `ruby` will think the parenthese as a part of parameter pass to `puts`:

```
$ ruby -rripper -rpp -e 'pp Ripper.sexp("puts (hello world).nil?")'
[:program,
 [[:command,
   [:@ident, "puts", [1, 0]],
   [:args_add_block,
    [[:call,
      [:paren,
       [:command,
        [:@ident, "hello", [1, 6]],
        [:args_add_block, [[:vcall, [:@ident, "world", [1, 12]]]], false]]],
      :".",
      [:@ident, "nil?", [1, 19]]]],
    false]]]]
```

In this case, parenthese is **paren**.